# python tkinter canvas create_line function returns values?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

i have recently encountered some return values in python interactive mode(i never get create_line function's return values in script mode and in case testing the lines individual in interactive mode i get return values but the function does not create lines like i expected). I was wondering what these meant and why is the line not getting created. Here are the few I have encountered till now:

```
>>> canvas.create_line(134,100,134,400)
1
>>>
```

and i got these return values too

```
>>> def shape():
    canvas.create_line(134,100,134,400)
    canvas.create_line(134,400,234,400)
    canvas.create_line(234,100,234,400)
    canvas.create_line(234,100,134,100)

    
>>> shape()
>>> canvas.create_line(134,100,134,400)
5
>>> canvas.create_line(134,400,234,400)
6
>>> canvas.create_line(234,100,234,400)
7
>>> canvas.create_line(234,100,134,100)
8
>>>
```

in this code, when i called `shape` function then it did not create the lines. Calling these lines individually gave me these return values, the odd this was how the values started from 5 and then went till 8 consecutively. Can someone please tell if this is a bug or do these numbers have a meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `canvas.create_line()` it returns an `Id` of the canvas object created, that later can be used to modify or get properties and so on.

Here is something about `create_arc()` as I could not find anything official about `create_line()`:

> The constructor returns the object ID of the new arc object on canvas.

From your example, seems like only `create_line()` and `create_image()` returns integer id, the rest gives an object id.

So for example:

```
obj = canvas.create_line(134,100,134,400)
canvas.itemconfig(obj, width=10)
```

`Canvas` methods take `tagorId`, so you can always just use an option `tag='line1'` and then call on it later, like:

```
obj = canvas.create_line(134,100,134,400,tag='line1')
canvas.itemconfig('line1', width=10)
```

> in this code, when I called shape function then it did not create the lines.

Are you sure the canvas coordinates are correct? It starts from 0,0 of the canvas, try changing the coordinates and configure what works for your canvas.

Comment: thx, your suggestion worked, I did not know tht tkinter does not auto-adjust coordinates. This time is got the root geometry when it was maximised and set canvas coordinates same, it worked. thx alot